# Linked list in c && use function to control

Tags: c, linked-list

```
typedef struct LIST{
    int count = 0;


}LIST;

typedef struct NODE{
    int data;
    struct NODE *link;
}NODE;

int main() {
    NODE *p1, *p2, *p3;

    p1 = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    p1->link = NULL;

    p2 = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    p2->data = 20;
    p2->link = NULL;
    p1->link = p2;
```

I want to make add NODE function and list to control NODE.
Give me some answer to solve this problem.

Comment: @EWit I want to make add node function  but I don't know how to make it. Function should connect link each others

Comment: I presume you know how a linked list works? What steps do you take in a linked list to add a new item to it? Work it out first on paper whilst being abstract and then work it out in C.

Answer (score 1):

you should define head in the list.

```
node * head;
```

Insert function as follows, to insert value in ascending order.

```
void insert(int val)
{
    node * nd = new node();
    nd->val = val;

   if(head == NULL)
        head = nd;
   else
   {
        if(val <= head->val) 
        {
            nd->next = head;
            head = nd;
        }
        else
        {
           node * itr = head;
           while(itr->next != NULL && itr->next->val <= val)
              itr = itr->next;
           nd->next = itr->next;
           itr->next = nd;
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you probably want to add to your LIST struct a field "NODE *first", which points to NULL initially, and then will point to the first element of your list.

Then what does you add function should do? Add to the beginning or the end of the list?
If at the beginning: allocate a NODE, set its link pointer to the first element of your list and say that the first element of the list is now the node that you just allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give variable according to their work, so that it is easy to understand.

```
struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node* next;
};

void insert(struct node** head_ref, int data)
{
    struct node* new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->val = data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = new_node; 
}
int main()
{
    struct node* head = NULL;
    insert(&head,1); 
    insert(&head,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that : Insert function will always add the value at front.

Try to write function for particular task.

Comment: Oh, thanks ... I'm the first for this site . So I don't know how to question and I'm not good at English, Thanks very much!!.

Comment: It's Okay. If you think this answer has solved your query, then accept this answer so that, in future if someone comes with same question, can immediately know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll avoid giving you the entire answer in C code since it's in general better to "teach a man to fish".

I would suggest that you add a NODE * member to your LIST class to store the header node of your linked list.

The addNode that adds a node to the next node should look like this:

```
void addNode (LIST* list, NODE * penultNode, int newData);
// list:       Address to the linked list info object
// penultNode: Address to the node after which you want to add a new node. 
//             Should be NULL if your linkedlist is empty
// newData:    Data in the new node that you wanna add
```

Inside this function, your actions will depend on whether penultNode is NULL or not. If it is not null, your job is simple. You just allocate a new NODE object and set the pointer of penultNode->next to the new object. If it is NULL, that means that no node exists in the list yet. In this case, you will need to set the pointer of list->headerNode to the new NODE object.